# ASP .NET Core Script-Migration : The term 'Script-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c#

En **ASP .NET core** al momento de ejecutar el comando `Add-Migration InitialMigration` en *Package Manager Console* me aparece este error:

```
Script-Migration : The term 'Script-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Script-Migration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Script-Migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

El nombre de la migración va dentro de corchetes, en tu ejemplo:
Add-Migration [MigracionInicial]

Comment: buenas tardes, al momento de ejecutar el comando Add-Migration InitialMigration, me aparece el error mencionado anteriormente

Comment: buenas tardes, al momento de ejecutar el comando Add-Migration InitialMigration, me aparece el error mencionado anteriormente, en ASP .NET Core

Comment: Pon el nombre de la migración dentro de corchetes []